# UICollectionView doesnot have resuseIdentifier error

Tags: ios, xcode6, uicollectionview

Code:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake([GRAPHICS SCREEN_WIDTH], 160);
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

m_collectShulList = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (m_imgBottomView.frameX + 160), [GRAPHICS SCREEN_WIDTH], 160) collectionViewLayout:layout];

[m_collectShulList setDataSource:self];
[m_collectShulList setDelegate:self];
[m_collectShulList setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[m_collectShulList setPagingEnabled:YES];

[self.m_bgImageView addSubview:m_collectShulList];
[m_collectShulList registerClass:[MSShulListCollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    MSShulListEntity *entity = [m_arrShulList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    MSShulListCollectionCell *Cell = (MSShulListCollectionCell *)[m_collectShulList dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Cell = [[MSShulListCollectionCell alloc]initWithWidth:[GRAPHICS SCREEN_WIDTH] withHeight:160.0 withName:entity.strShulName withAddress:entity.strShulAddress withPhone:entity.strShulPhone withSchedule:entity.strShulShedule withLikeCount:entity.strShulLikeCount];

    Cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    Cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];    

    return Cell;
}
```

I create UICollectionView programatically. I have done the layout and registering everything. It throws error as

> "NSInternalInconsistencyException", reason: 'the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'".

I double checked my code. What am I missing?

Comment: Why have reinitialized Cell if already dequeueing??

Comment: i created label, image and button in that method..

Answer (score 0):

Your table view cell should be initialized from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath :` method, and you should set your property to the cell dequeued with this method.

So try to implement your delegate method as

```
MSShulListCollectionCell *cell = (MSShulListCollectionCell *)[m_collectShulList dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.width = ...;
cell.height = ...;
cell.name = ...;
```

Simply you can modify your `initWithWidth:...` and make it a 'setup method' and call it to set your label and image once the cell is dequeued.